# Efficient way to apply row-specific conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have data on outbound flights, with info on the day, month, airport etc.
I would like to go through the rows, and for each of them, count the number of flights that where leaving from the same airport in +- 15m.
My code seems to work, but is very slow (on 100k rows it takes ~an hour to run).
Is there a way to improve its efficiency?
Here is a sample file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iBpOAvhOJ9Qi7a50IB_Ys_YGiTLhMElv/view?usp=sharing)
Thanks!

```
time_allowance = 15
close_out = []
i=0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    i+=1

    idf = df.loc[(df['Origin'] == row['Origin']) &
                 (df['Month'] == row['Month']) &
                 (df['DayofMonth'] == row['DayofMonth']) &
                 (df['DepTime'] < row['DepTime'] + time_allowance) &
                 (df['DepTime'] > row['DepTime'] - time_allowance), :]

    close_out.append(len(idf))   

col_name = 'close_out' + str(time_allowance)
df[col_name] = close_out
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: I think I'd `set_index` to datetime, `groupby` Origin and iterate over the groups applying a rolling window of +/-15min... However, a [mcve] would be fine...

Comment: @jezrael added the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Your code

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['Month', 'DayofMonth', 'DayOfWeek', 'DepTime', 'UniqueCarrier', 'Origin', 'Dest', 'Distance']
data = [
  ['c-8', 'c-21', 'c-7', 1934, 'AA', 'ATL', 'DFW', 732],
  ['c-6', 'c-19', 'c-2', 1942, 'AA', 'ATL', 'CLE', 999],
  ['c-6', 'c-19', 'c-2', 1955, 'AA', 'ATL', 'CLE', 111],
  ['c-4', 'c-20', 'c-3', 1548, 'US', 'PIT', 'MCO', 834],
  ['c-9', 'c-2', 'c-5', 1422, 'XE', 'RDU', 'CLE', 416],
  ['c-11', 'c-25', 'c-6', 1015, 'OO', 'DEN', 'MEM', 872],
  ['c-10', 'c-7', 'c-6', 1828, 'WN', 'MDW', 'OMA', 423]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)
df['close_out15'] = 0

def algo_v1(df):


time_allowance = 15
  close_out = []
  i=0
  for index, row in df.iterrows():
      i+=1

      idf = df.loc[(df['Origin'] == row['Origin']) &
                  (df['Month'] == row['Month']) &
                  (df['DayofMonth'] == row['DayofMonth']) &
                  (df['DepTime'] < row['DepTime'] + time_allowance) &
                  (df['DepTime'] > row['DepTime'] - time_allowance), :]

      close_out.append(len(idf))   

  col_name = 'close_out' + str(time_allowance)
  df[col_name] = close_out

  return df
```

### Testing:

```
#print(algo_v1(df))
#%timeit algo_v1(df)

      Month DayofMonth DayOfWeek  DepTime  ... Origin Dest Distance  close_out15
0   c-8       c-21       c-7     1934  ...    ATL  DFW      732            1
1   c-6       c-19       c-2     1942  ...    ATL  CLE      999            2
2   c-6       c-19       c-2     1955  ...    ATL  CLE      111            2
3   c-4       c-20       c-3     1548  ...    PIT  MCO      834            1
4   c-9        c-2       c-5     1422  ...    RDU  CLE      416            1
5  c-11       c-25       c-6     1015  ...    DEN  MEM      872            1
6  c-10        c-7       c-6     1828  ...    MDW  OMA      423            1

[7 rows x 9 columns]
10 loops, best of 3: 28.4 ms per loop
```

---

### Some basic improvement just using `groupby`and `apply` methods.

```
def filter_and_count(df):
  time_threshold = 15

  for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    row['close_out15'] = df['UniqueCarrier'].loc[
      (df['DepTime'] <= row['DepTime'] + time_threshold)
      & (df['DepTime'] >= row['DepTime'] - time_threshold)
    ].count()


def algo_v2(df):
  df.groupby(['Origin', 'Month', 'DayofMonth']).apply(filter_and_count)

  return df
```

### Testing performance

```
#print(algo_v2(df))
#%timeit algo_v2(df)

  Month DayofMonth DayOfWeek  DepTime  ... Origin Dest Distance  close_out15
0   c-8       c-21       c-7     1934  ...    ATL  DFW      732            1
1   c-6       c-19       c-2     1942  ...    ATL  CLE      999            2
2   c-6       c-19       c-2     1955  ...    ATL  CLE      111            2
3   c-4       c-20       c-3     1548  ...    PIT  MCO      834            1
4   c-9        c-2       c-5     1422  ...    RDU  CLE      416            1
5  c-11       c-25       c-6     1015  ...    DEN  MEM      872            1
6  c-10        c-7       c-6     1828  ...    MDW  OMA      423            1

[7 rows x 9 columns]
100 loops, best of 3: 18.8 ms per loop
```

An **improvement of about 34%** can be noticed just grouping by some fields.

### Next stepts for improving performance

There are two major options:

- Continue improving performace of the algorithm
- Parallelization

Note that the two options may work together as well.

#### Improving performance

Using [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) or [Ctyhon](https://cython.org/) might be [good options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html).

#### Parallelization

[Multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) is an alternative. Other more high-level abstraction option is [this one](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html).

Comment: Wow, cool! Any other ideas on efficiency improvements?
Thank you very much for the working code, but if you point me in some directions - that would also be fine (I would hate wasting too much of your time on writing my code :))

Comment: I will edit my answer adding some guide lines to continue improving performance @StanislavNosulenko

Comment: I guess this closes it - I will be trying to implement this stuff as best as I Can :) Thank you @BSP!